# PostgreSQL 11.5/ 12: The database cluster initialization failed Windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-10

I have tried the solution [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/postgresql-the-database-cluster-initialization-failed) by Imraan and this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453451/postgres-installation-the-database-cluster-initialization-failed-postgresql-ve) by ThangLeQuoc.

When running stage 7 I still get the error 'Access denied' and cannot install the program.

I have tried to to open new file folder for postgres and check the permissions, it had all the permissions.

I have noticed that during the installing if I open a data folder somewhere else and give it permissions some new user named 'CREATOR USER' is created with no permissions (only for the data folder) then the folder disappears and return.

By the end of the installing I get the error:

```
The database cluster initialization failed
```

and no server is installed.

Anyone got another solution? I have tried searching for a day and could not figure out how to fix it.

Thanks!

p.s I tried for postgres 12 and 11.5 and windows 10.