# Getting Database cluster error while installing PostgreSql 12 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql

When I tried to install PostgreSql 11/12 on my windows machine I was getting the below error :

**Error while initializing database cluster**

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Below are the details - 
Port No - 5432
Installation Location - I have tried installing it in C:/ProgramFiles and also directly in C drive
Password - test123 
I am running the installer as administrator
I have access to Temp directory as well.
I have tried moving data folder outside of the main folder.
Below are the solutions I have tried -

- [Sol 1](https://postgresrocks.enterprisedb.com/t5/PostgreSQL/Installing-PostgreSQL-12-on-Windows-fails-when-initialising-the/td-p/4511/)
- [Sol 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453451/postgres-installation-the-database-cluster-initialization-failed-postgresql-ve)

Below is the error in log file:

```
Error running cscript //NoLogo "C:\pg/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\Users\u6105742\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_2714a75545" "C:\pg" "C:\pg\data" 5432 "DEFAULT" 0: Program ended with an error exit code
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
The database cluster initialisation failed.
Executing icacls "C:\Users\u6105742\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_e172900ce0" /inheritance:r Script exit code: 0
```

Could someone please help me in this issue?

Comment: Read the installation log, maybe it has more details.

Comment: Yes, I selected a path outside of C:\Program FIles. I do have full privileges for that folder. I have antivirus installed. I will try disabling it and install it again.

Comment: Can you try to run initdb manually? `"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\initdb" -D C:\pg\data` (adjust the path to `initdb.exe` according to your installation path)

Comment: @AashmiChaudhary: I have added an answer with a bit more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows I typically don't use the installer any more as its attempt to set privileges correctly is laudable but seems to create more problems than it solves (especially with computers that a part of a Windows domain seem to suffer from that).

Manually running `initdb` seems to be more robust, but you **will** have to fix the permissions on the data directory yourself, e.g.:

```
"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\initdb" -D C:\pg\data
```

If you want a Windows service, this can be done using pg_ctl:

```
"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl" register -N postgresql-12 -D C:\pg\data
```

---

The Windows service will run using the Windows ["Local System"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/the-localsystem-account) account which sometimes is seen [as dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170) - but isn't as dangerous as described in that SO answer, because Postgres will drop all elevated privileges when it starts the service.

Comment: "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\initdb" -D C:\pg\data
I try to run this and I get that postgre is not on same folder, but it is!!! Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this is the folllowing:

1. Download the Postgres installer for Windows (EDB site)
2. Open a Powershell with admin rights and execute the following:

   `.\postgresql-<version>-windows-x64.exe --install_runtimes 0 --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --superpassword "<set your superuser password here>" --servicename "postgreSQL"`

Replace the < version > with the current version you are trying to install and the superuser password of your choice.

It will install everything and create a service called postgreSQL.