# Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly The database cluster initialisation failed

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

Installing PostgreSQL v12.3 on Windows 10 with Windows x86-64 installer. I can't find a solution anywhere. Installer allows me to click ok and continue installation. I even have access to all the apps that come with Postgres, including the pgAdmin4 app, but I the 'psql' command in my command line doesn't work.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Try to initialize the data directory manually: See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61115811/330315

Comment: Thank you for the resource. I followed the steps and got a response but I'm not sure if it is what I needed yet. My main concern was getting the psql command to work in the terminal and I was able to accomplish that by adding a new variable to the environment Path variables. The directions to getting the psql command to work in the terminal were found here: https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/setting-windows-path-for-postgres-tools